# iPhone 5C taking >25 minutes to charge from a dead battery from <8 hours ago

Tags: iphone, charging

I have an iPhone 5C, and I left it in the charger for >25 minutes to recover from a dead battery within the last 8 hours. It will not turn on. The charger works. It can charge another iPhone (6 Plus). The iPhone (5C) shows a dead battery with charger when not plugged in. When it is, it shows a dead battery without a charger. I have not had any water damage, ever. I don't know if there is a way to force power on an iPhone. iTunes does not recognize it, but the iPhone does charge from the USB port it is plugged into. For 25 minutes it has been in an Apple USB wall adapter block. There are no signs of physical damage. It is iOS 7.x or 8.x, but not 9.x. It did not have 3D touch, if that helps.

Note: I am using a non-Apple charger that has worked before in the same phone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My experience has been that some (most?) **non-MFi** chargers/cables are unable to bring an iPhone out of a completely discharged state. In the past, I’ve had to use an **MFi-certified** Apple charger/cable first; only after the iPhone came back to life did the unofficial charger work.